# jira bulk update custom field value

Tags: jira

I need to update all the values of a custom field in Jira.  I noticed the "Bulk Fix Resolutions" script which is kind of what I want, but not for resolutions, for custom field value. Any thoughts on what I need to do?

Answer (score 2):

A groovy script run in the ScriptRunner console. Carefully tested in staging beforehand. Or an external script such as jira-python

Answer (score 2):

Thanks I found the answer here, it can be done with existing UI:

Using the bulk change wizard - The bulk change wizard will progress you through your bulk change. To step back at any step of the operation, select the relevant step in the menu on the left-hand side. Selecting Cancel will cancel the entire process.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/jiracoreserver074/editing-multiple-issues-at-the-same-time-921047221.html?_ga=2.18023408.858755321.1517851422-336306238.1516208522